# Futter :- Start vibrating or ringing phone continuously after sending specific notification

Tags: android, ios, flutter, push-notification, vibration

When I triggered specific type of notification to the specific group of user then their phone will start vibrating or ringing phone continuously until user not stop from the App.
Can anyone suggest how can I make possible? or Any packages which useful in terminate state and start vibrating in all state?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide snippets code over here. Might be possible you have initialise your notification class in build method instead of initState method.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    NotificationHandler().initializeFcmNotification();
  }
```